# encoding a yuv file into mpeg2 using mpegencoder

Tags: video, video-encoding, yuv, mpeg-2

I wanted to compress a .yuv using a mpeg-2 standard. So, I have downloaded the mpegencoder of MSSG. Below is the code for the parameters file.
 But I don't know how to store the output video. Please help me with this issue. I want to single and double compressed videos using mpeg-2 standard.Is there another software which could serve this purpose.

```
 akiyo_cif    /* name of source files */
-        /* name of reconstructed images ("-": don't store) */
-         /* name of intra quant matrix file     ("-": default matrix) 
*/ 
-         /* name of non intra quant matrix file ("-": default matrix) 
*/
-         /* name of statistics file ("-": stdout ) */
1         /* input picture file format: 0=*.Y,*.U,*.V, 1=*.yuv, 
           2=*.ppm   
*/ 
3 00         /* number of frames */
0         /* number of first frame */
23:59:59:24 /* timecode of first frame */
6         /* N (# of frames in GOP) */
2         /* M (I/P frame distance) */
0         /* ISO/IEC 11172-2 stream */
0         /* 0:frame pictures, 1:field pictures */
352       /* horizontal_size */
288       /* vertical_size */
2         /* aspect_ratio_information 1=square pel, 2=4:3, 3=16:9, 
4=2.11:1 */
3         /* frame_rate_code 2=23.976, 3=25, 4=29.97, 5=30 
           frames/second */
400000.0  /* bit_rate (bits/s) */
6         /* vbv_buffer_size (in multiples of 16 kbit) */
0         /* low_delay  */`enter code here`
0         /* constrained_parameters_flag */
 4         /* Profile ID: Simple = 5, Main = 4, SNR = 3, Spatial = 2, 
             High = 1 */`enter code here`
 8         /* Level ID:   Low = 10, Main = 8, High 1440 = 6, High = 4          
              */
 0         /* progressive_sequence */
 1         /* chroma_format: 1=4:2:0, 2=4:2:2, 3=4:4:4 */
1         /* video_format: 0=comp., 1=PAL, 2=NTSC, 3=SECAM, 4=MAC, 
5=unspec. */
5         /* color_primaries */
5         /* transfer_characteristics */
5         /* matrix_coefficients */
 352       /* display_horizontal_size */
 288       /* display_vertical_size */
1         /* intra_dc_precision (0: 8 bit, 1: 9 bit, 2: 10 bit, 3: 11 
          bit */
1         /* top_field_first */
1 0 0     /* frame_pred_frame_dct (I P B) */
0 0 0     /* concealment_motion_vectors (I P B) */
0 1 1     /* q_scale_type  (I P B) */
1 1 0     /* intra_vlc_format (I P B)*/
1 0 1     /* alternate_scan (I P B) */
0         /* repeat_first_field */
0         /* progressive_frame */
0         /* P distance between complete intra slice refresh */
0         /* rate control: r (reaction parameter) */
0         /* rate control: avg_act (initial average activity) */
 0         /* rate control: Xi (initial I frame global complexity 
       measure) */
 0         /* rate control: Xp (initial P frame global complexity 
     measure) */
 0         /* rate control: Xb (initial B frame global complexity 
       measure) */
    0         /* rate control: d0i (initial I frame virtual buffer 
       fullness) */
  0         /* rate control: d0p (initial P frame virtual buffer 
           fullness) */
  0         /* rate control: d0b (initial B frame virtual buffer 
         fullness) */
      2 2 11 11 /* P:  forw_hor_f_code forw_vert_f_code 
        search_width/height */
      1 1 3  3  /* B1: forw_hor_f_code forw_vert_f_code 
       search_width/height */
      1 1 7  7  /* B1: back_hor_f_code back_vert_f_code 
       search_width/height */
       1 1 7  7  /* B2: forw_hor_f_code forw_vert_f_code 
       search_width/height */
   1 1 3  3  /* B2: back_hor_f_code back_vert_f_code 
        search_width/height */
```

Comment: Seriously: use [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/about.html) (or explain why not).

Comment: Thanks for your help. Can you elucidate the procedure on how to use FFmpeg to encode .yuv using mpeg-2 standard.

Comment: Start [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778774/using-ffmpeg-to-losslessly-convert-yuv-to-another-format-for-editing-in-adobe-pr) (where you probably only would replace the encoder) and do some own research. Your question is broad.