# Error trying to use cvtColor with cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR_Y422 - error: (-215) scn == 2 && depth == 0 in function cv::cvtColor

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, yuv

I want to read a YUV video with openCV. The YUV video is 1920*1080 and use the YUV422 format (I already tried to read this video with yuviewer and it worked)

I am using Python3.6.4 with an Anaconda environnement with OpenCV 3.3.1

First I tried this script https://stackoverflow.com/a/47815385/8236556 but this line

```
cv2.cvtColor(yuv, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR_Y422)
```

is giving me this error.

```
  File "read-yuv-video.py", line 29, in <module>
    bgr = cv2.cvtColor(yuv, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR_UYVY)
cv2.error: C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11228: error: (-215) scn == 2 && depth == 0 in function cv::cvtColor
```

I also have this error when try to convert from Y444 or Y420 to RGB or RGBA or GREY.
I didn't find the exact same error on google or stackoverflow.
I tried to reinstall the opencv package but it didn't worked.

In my script below every cvtColor works except the last one. By working I mean it display the image but the wrong colors.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# filename = r'C:\myPath\voile.yuv'
filename = r'C:\myPath\credits.yuv'
yuv_file = open(filename, 'rb')
frame_len = 1920 * 1080 * 3/2
shape = (int(1080 * 1.5), 1920)
raw = yuv_file.read(int(frame_len))
yuv = np.frombuffer(raw, dtype=np.uint8)
yuv = yuv.reshape(shape)
yuv = cv2.resize(yuv, (0, 0), fx=0.5, fy=0.5)

cv2.imshow("raw yuv", yuv)
cv2.waitKey(0)

bgr = cv2.cvtColor(yuv, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV21)
cv2.imshow("YUV2BGR_NV21", bgr)
cv2.waitKey(0)

bgr = cv2.cvtColor(yuv, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR_NV12)
cv2.imshow("YUV2BGR_NV12", bgr)
cv2.waitKey(0)

bgr = cv2.cvtColor(yuv, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR_I420)
cv2.imshow("YUV2BGR_I420", bgr)
cv2.waitKey(0)

bgr = cv2.cvtColor(yuv, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR_Y422)
cv2.imshow("YUV2BGR_Y422", bgr)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

**Edit**

scn == 2 means the function needs a 2 channels image.
I changed these lines:

```
frame_len = 1920 * 1080 * 2 # 4 Bytes for 2 pixels
shape = (height, width, 2) # To have a 2 channels image (not really working obviously)
```

and cv2.cvtColor is not throwing an error anymore but still not working properly. I assume my reshape is completely wrong.

My results:

- [Original frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0j6R2.jpg)
- [Raw frame, reshape(height*2, width)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0sSs2.png)
- [YUV2BGR_Y422, reshape(height, width, 2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O2lu1.png)

I looked manually in the numpy.array and compared with YUView the value of pixels and the shape correspond to what I am expecting (the Y values then U then V) but that's not what opencv is displaying.

Why there is 4 images below the Y matrix in the raw frame?

More precisely, how should be the shape of the datas in input of the cv2.cvtColor function in my case?

Comment: `scn` means "Source image number of channels". | The different YUV variants use different number of bits to represent a pixel. For example Y422 uses 4 bytes per 2 pixels, so OpenCV expects a 2 channel image. That's obviously not the case, since when you load the data, you load 1.5 bytes/pixel and treat it as single channel. Similarly, Y444 uses 3 bytes per pixel, so if the input image was actually using that format, you're missing half the data.

Comment: @DanMašek Now the function is 'working' (not throwing an error) but the color and the shape of the image are wrong. What should contain the 2 channels? In my new script I'm using yuv.reshape(height, width, 2) but I don't know how reshape works and I don't see how this can works considering the shape of the datas. In the frame I get, the firsts 1920*1080 pixels are Y, the 1920*1080/2 which follow are U and then the same number for V.

Comment: Using ffmpeg first to convert the video I have been able to read the video with opencv. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778774/using-ffmpeg-to-losslessly-convert-yuv-to-another-format-for-editing-in-adobe-pr

Comment: Then my objective was to compute some metrics with sk-video and it's also using ffmpeg to load the video in the skvideo.io.vread function. Then you can test if the format is the good one by displaying the matrix with matplotlib.

Before formating the video you can test which YUV format it is with:
YUView: guess the good format most of the time
yuvplayer: lighter

Comment: here is the vread function in my case:
    video = skvideo.io.vread(
        filename,
        height=1080,
        width=1920,
        num_frames=num_frames,
        backend='ffmpeg',
        verbosity=0,
        as_grey=True,
        inputdict={
            '-r': '20',
            '-pix_fmt': 'yuv422p',
            '-video_size': '1920x1080'
            }
        )

Answer (score 1):

As YUV 4:2:2 has some variants, it would be easier if you can find exactly what is your YUV format. I use Logitech Brio Webcam to shoot YUV videos with ffmpeg which gives me the YUV in `(YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422`. This is also the YUV 4:2:2 but has some differences in the order of bytes.

As YUV 4:2:2 compression ratio is 2/3, you were correct to use 2 bytes for 1 pixel. This worked for me.

```
frame_len = int(width * height * 2)
shape = (height, width, 2)
```

And to convert from YUV to BGR (opencv format):

```
bgr = cv2.cvtColor(yuv, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGR_YUY2)
```